# Deserialize Json without knowing type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm consuming a websockets api and I have one method that receives all incoming responses. The responses are all json.

I would like to deserialize the json response to a typed object but how do I know *what* type it is?

1) Inspect the raw json for keyword strings

2) Attempt to deserialize to each type until one of them isn't null

3) `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to a `JObject` and somehow convert to my final type

I'm not sure what's the cleanest solution or how to even solve this.

Comment: How do you differentiate which object you are receiving? Is there a "type" property, or is it more complicated?

Comment: It's more complicated. Sometimes it's just raw text and not even json. Nothing that I've seen in any of the responses that would help me other than finding combinations of field names

Comment: Your question says "the responses are all json".  But your comment says "sometimes it's just raw text and not even json".  Please clarify your inputs.

Comment: @Tim I'm ignoring all text responses and my question is only about the json responses which is why I omitted it from the question.

Comment: Personally, this seems like a very bad/suspect api, if you wrote this api, i would consider re-thinking it to have more concrete information about what is coming through

Comment: @TheGeneral It's not mine, it's actually a large crypto exchange. I've seen other clients in GitHub but they all seems to use option #2 which just doesn't feel right to me. I'll probably end up inspecting the raw json but now the problem has me interested in what the proper solution would be.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `dynamic` types if you really have no idea what type to expect. This will work just fine with Newtonsoft

```
dynamic theObject = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
```

Then when you have a JSON response like this:

```
{
    "name": "Deep Thought",
    "answer": "42"
}
```

Then you can get to the properties like so:

```
dynamic hitchhiker = JObject.Parse(rawJson);
Console.WriteLine(hitchhiker.name);
```

This will output the following:

> Deep Thought

Comment: But I don't know which type is coming through to know that `name` property would even exist.